# When and why are Adams operations "non-negative"?

Tags: rt.representation-theory, kt.k-theory-and-homology, lambda-rings

We can think of the unary operations in a lambda-ring as integer linear combinations of Young diagrams; for example the operation $\lambda^n$ corresponds to the Young diagram with $n$ rows and one column.

Some of these operations are **manifestly non-negative** in the following sense: they're linear combinations of Young diagrams with *natural number* coefficients.

If we apply a manifestly non-negative operation to an element of the representation ring $R(G)$ coming from a representation of $G$, we get another element coming from a representation - not just a formal difference of such elements.   Similarly, if we apply a manifestly non-negative operation to an element of the K-theory $K(X)$ coming from a vector bundle on $X$, we get another element coming from a vector bundle - not just a formal difference of such elements.

I'm confused about Adams operations.  For $k > 1$, the Adams operation $\psi_k$ is apparently *not* manifestly non-negative, since it's given by an [alternating sum of hook-shaped Young diagrams with $k$ boxes](https://golem.ph.utexas.edu/~distler/blog/archives/001976.html).

However, if we apply $\psi_k$ to an element of $K(X)$ coming from a vector bundle over $X$, I believe we get an element coming from a vector bundle.  It's certainly true for line bundles: $\psi_k [L] = [L^{\otimes k}]$ when $[L]$ is the element of $K$-theory coming from a line bundle $L$.   It's also true for bundles that split as a sum of line bundles, since $\psi_k : K(X) \to K(X)$ is a ring homomorphism.   And I think it follows for all vector bundles using the splitting principle for K-theory ([Corollary 4.3.4 here](https://www.dpmms.cam.ac.uk/~or257/teaching/notes/Kthy.pdf)).

So, it seems that the Adams operations, while not manifestly non-negative, are still **non-negative** in the sense that they send elements of $K(X)$) coming  vector bundles to elements coming from vector bundles - not merely formal differences of such.

My questions are:

1) Is this true?

2) If so, which integer linear combinations of Young diagrams give operations that are non-negative in this sense?

3) What's really going on here?  In particular, I've defined "non-negative" using $K(X)$, but these should be examples of a more general phenomenon.  The Grothendieck ring $K(C)$ of any [symmetric monoidal Cauchy-complete $\mathbb{Q}$-linear category](https://ncatlab.org/johnbaez/show/Schur+functors+I#schur_functors_on_more_general_categories) $C$ is a lambda-ring, in a way that generalizes this.  We can define "non-negative" operations on $K(C)$ to be those sending elements coming from objects of $C$ to elements coming from objects of $C$.   Are Adams operations always non-negative on $K(C)$, or this just true for certain $C$?  Which $C$ are these?  And which linear combinations of Young diagrams give operations that are non-negative on $K(C)$ for *all* symmetric monoidal Cauchy-complete $C$?

Comment: For $\rho$ a representation, $\rho(g^k)$ is not a representation unless $G$ is a abelian. No operation preserves non negativity for all groups unless it is a nonnegative combination of Schur functors, as you can see by plugging in the standard representation of $GL_n$. An operation preserves non negativity in the representation ring of all abelian groups if and only if the associated symmetric polynomial has nonnegative coefficients.

Comment: There might be many examples of operations that are only nonnegative for symmetric monoidal abelian categories of a certain type. Simple Lie groups with no automorphisms of their Dynkin diagram have only self-dual representations, making $\operatorname{Sym}^2 V + \wedge^2 V -1$ nonnegative, at least when $V$ is nonzero.

Comment: "For $\rho$ a representation, $\rho(g^k)$ is not a representation unless $G$ is abelian."  Oh, duh.  I guess this somehow analogous to the splitting principle then: people study Adams operations on $\mathrm{Rep}(G)$ with $G$ a compact Lie group by looking at what they do to $\mathrm{Rep}(T)$ when $T$ is a maximal torus, where the formula I gave actually makes sense!

Comment: Given the mistake that Will Sawin caught, I'm gonna delete the stuff about representation rings in my original post.   Nonetheless I'm happy to hear about which lambda-operations are nonnegative in which representation rings.

Comment: Just for clarity I think the splitting principle argument is also wrong. The map being objective on $K$-theory implies almost nothing about what it does on vector bundle classes. Probably the tangent bundle to $\mathbb P^2$ provides a counterexample.

Comment: Right, I get it now.  The splitting principle is good for reducing identities between characteristic classes to the case where a vector bundle is a sum of line bundles, but of no use for what I was trying to use it for.

Comment: @WillSawin The tangent bundle to $\mathbb{P}^{n}$ is stably a sum of line bundles, so I don' t think that will work. More precisely, if $T$ is the tangent bundle then there's a line bundle $L$ with $[T]=(n+1)[L] - 1$. Applying $\psi^{k}$ we get $(n+1)[L^{k}]-1$. But the first term is a rank $n+1$ bundle with zero top chern class, so it has a nonvanishing section. That means "subtracting 1" actually makes sense at the level of bundles. I think a similar argument will get you non-negativity of the Adams operations on anything that's stably a difference of line bundles.

Comment: @JohnGreenwood Good point. Maybe a rank-2 tautological bundle on a Grassmanian $G(2,n)$ for $n$ sufficiently large will do the trick instead, as these approximate the classifying space of $GL_2$ and the standard rep of $GL_2$ gives a counterexample.

Answer (score 4):

The Adams operations aren't always non-negative. (They are if you restrict to the subring generated by line bundles, though.)

Here's a counterexample in the world of finite CW-complexes. Let $X$ be the truncated projective space $\mathbb{RP}^{2n-1}/\mathbb{RP}^{2t-1}$. It's reduced $K$-theory was calculated by Adams [here](https://apurvanakade.github.io/notes/CMI/vector%20fields%20on%20spheres/adams2.pdf) to be $\mathbb{Z}\oplus\mathbb{Z}/2^{n-t}\mathbb{Z}$. Let $\mu$ and $\nu$ be generators of each factor. They are best understood as follows. The inclusion of the $2t$-skeleton gives a map $S^{2t}\hookrightarrow X$. Pulling back along this map sends $\mu$ to a generator of $\tilde{K}(S^{2t})$. Let $\eta$ be the complexified tautological line bundle over $\mathbb{RP}^{2n-1}$. Pulling back along the quotient map $\mathbb{RP}^{2n-1}\rightarrow X$ sends $\nu$ to the class $([\eta]-1)^{t+1}=(-2)^{t}([\eta]-1)$. Note that the last equality is a simple consequence of the fact that real line bundles are self dual. Adams also calculated the effect of the Adams operations on these generators. For example, if $k$ is odd then $$\psi^{k}\mu=k^{t}\mu+\frac{k^{t}-1}{2}\nu$$
(Sidenote: that 2 in the denominator is the poison dart in Adams' vector-fields-on-spheres proof. For our purposes it is only important that $\psi^{k}\mu$ has a component in both the $\mu$ and $\nu$ factor. If we add a $t$ dimensional trivial bundle to the class $\mu$, then it is represented by an honest bundle $V$, which can be constructed via clutching, by cutting apart the $S^{2t}$ that comprises the $2t$-skeleton of $X$. Therefore,
$$\psi^{k}[V]=k^{t}[V]+ t -k^{t}t +\frac{k^{t}-1}{2}[\eta]  -\frac{k^{t}-1}{2}$$
Multiplying the clutching function of $V$ by $k^{t}$ (as an element in $\pi_{2t-1}U(t)=\mathbb{Z}$ gives a vector bundle $V_{k^{t}}$ representing $k^{t}\mu+t$, so
$$\psi^{k}[V]=[V_{k^{t}}]+\frac{k^{t}-1}{2}[\eta] -\frac{k^{t}-1}{2}$$
Now, it's a general fact that if $E$ is a vector bundle such that the class $[E]-n$ is representable by a vector bundle, then the last $n$ Chern classes of $E$ must be zero. We can achieve this obstruction in our example by choosing the right $k$, $n$, and $t$. The first term has a single non-vanishing (top) chern class, which is $k^{t}$ times a generator of $H^{2t}(X)=\mathbb{Z}$, and the chern class of the second term is easily understood in terms of the chern class of $\eta$. In particular its top chern class will be nonzero as long as $n$ is very large.